# How can I use firebase to save database for users account?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a note-taking application and wanted to create it in a firebase database so users can sign in with their Google Accounts. When you save a note, it will be in the cloud. When they install the application on other devices (or reinstall), so when they log in they will have what they had before.
Is this possible? If you know something please give me some lift. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is some really good documentation from Google to use authentication with Firebase. Here is a good place to start : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

For Google Authentication specifically, look here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin